# Make Form Invalid without Raising ValidationError in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

I would like a form to be invalid without raising a ValidationError in any of the form's or form's field's clean methods.  The reason for this is that the form is the "super form" for a set of "sub forms", and I want the super form to be invalid when any of its subforms are invalid.  But this invalidity does not entail raising a ValidationError in the super form, and in fact I do not want to raise a ValidationError in the super form because I do not want any error message to appear in the super form's error lists (avoiding the display of an error message in the super form's `non_field_errors` is my main motivation here.)  One way around this for me would be to check both the super form and its sub forms for `is_valid` in the view, but I prefer to check only the super form and have its `is_valid` return `False` even when its fields are valid, but when one or more of its sub forms returns `False` to `is_valid`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you override the is_valid method?

```
class SuperForm(forms.Form):
  def is_valid(self):
    return forms.Form.is_valid(self) and all(form.is_valid() for form in self.sub_forms)
```

Comment: I think this is the correct option.  I was not aware of the `all` function in python; that function will cleanup my code in several places, I think.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean to call `forms.Form.is_valid(self)`?  What about `super(SuperForm, self).is_valid()`?